# Loop to change elements in large list (6 at a time) and create a new variable for each iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, plotly, slice

I am making a wind rose using plotly that uses drop down menus to plot each month. I want to clean up my code a bit using a loop, but have had success using a rudimentary way and want to learn more in the process.

Some quick background:
Plotly uses 'traces' to plot the specific types of data (I have 6 different traces per month representing the wind speed bins). To get a drop down menu to work, you need a list of bools stating what is visible. For example if I wanted January's data, I'd need a list of 78 bools for 12 months and the annual total data, with list elements 5-11 being true and the rest being false.

Here is the aforementioned rudimentary, albeit working code.

```
TF = [False]*78
TF[0:5]=[True]*6
Ann_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[6:11]=[True]*6
Jan_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[12:17]=[True]*6
Feb_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[18:23]=[True]*6
Mar_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[24:29]=[True]*6
Apr_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[30:35]=[True]*6
May_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[36:41]=[True]*6
Jun_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[42:47]=[True]*6
Jul_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[48:53]=[True]*6
Aug_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[54:59]=[True]*6
Sep_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[60:65]=[True]*6
Oct_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[66:71]=[True]*6
Nov_L = TF.copy()

TF = [False]*78
TF[72:77]=[True]*6
Dec_L = TF.copy()
```

As you can see, I make a large list, edit the 6 element slice, copy to a new variable and re-do for each month. I simply just want to loop this to clean it up. Any help would be appreciated.

Example variables in use

```
fig.update_layout(
updatemenus=[
    dict(
        x=0.1,
        xanchor="left",
        y=0.99,
        yanchor="top",
        active=0,
        showactive= True,
        buttons=list([
            dict(label="Annual",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible": Ann_L},
                       {"title": "Annual"}]),
            dict(label="January",
                 method="update",
                 args=[{"visible": Jan_L},
                       {"title": "January"}]),
```

Comment: How are you using the variables Jan_L etc. provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example including these variables and how you are plotting them. It would help in restructuring/using dictionaries to map traces etc.

Comment: edited in the code where I use the variables. All it represents is one long list of bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### List of lists

You could create all the lists using list comprehension and then assign each list to the relevant variable using destructuring.

```py
L = [[False]*(n*6)+[True]*6+[False]*(73-n*6) for n in range(0, 13)]

Ann_L, Jan_L, Feb_L, Mar_L, Apr_L, May_L, Jun_L, Jul_L, Aug_L, Sep_L, Oct_L, Nov_L, Dec_L = L
```

### Dictionary of lists

Here's an alternative which creates a dictionary with the keys `Ann_L, Jan_L, Feb_L etc.`

To use this you will need to adjust your code to use `months['Ann_L'] etc.`

```py
names = ['Ann_L', 'Jan_L', 'Feb_L', 'Mar_L', 'Apr_L', 'May_L', 'Jun_L', 
         'Jul_L', 'Aug_L', 'Sep_L', 'Oct_L', 'Nov_L', 'Dec_L']

months = {names[n]: [False]*(n*6)+[True]*6+[False]*(73-n*6) for n in range(0, 13)}
```

Comment: That's good.  In fact, I was going to argue (with virtually the same answer) that the OP should just keep the months in a list of lists, instead of assigning separate variables, which are almost always more awkward to work with.  Call it something like `Months`.

Comment: wow, this great, this works perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. thank you

Comment: This is a very elegant solution with a single list comprehension. I was going to suggest using itertools which is definitely a bit heavy handed

Comment: Took me a bit to figure out what was going on besides being a successful solution, but very elegant indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can even construct your buttons dynamically like this

```py
from calendar import month_name

months = list(month_name)
months[0] = 'Annual'
buttons = [{
    'label': months[i],
    'method': 'update',
    'args': [{'visible': [False]*(i*6)+[True]*6+[False]*(73-i*6)}, {'title': month_name[i]}]
} for i in range(13)]
```

You don't have to create variables that abbreviate month names

**EDIT**: Fixed 'args' to be a list